# How to merge array of arrays by key in php?

Tags: php, arrays

So questions of this nature have been asked 1000 times on stack overflow, but none of them I've searched through so far address the issue that I'm having. I have two arrays like this:

```
$cupcake_sales = [
   ['date' => '05/09/1992', 'num_cupcakes_sold' => 30 ],
   ['date' => '05/11/1992', 'num_cupcakes_sold' => 25 ],
];
```

and another array like this:

```
$cupcake_revenue = [
    ['date' => '05/10/1992', 'revenue' => '$40'],
    ['date' => '05/11/1992', 'revenue' => '$100'],
];
```

what I need is an array like this:

```
$cupcake_sales_revenue = [
    ['date' => '05/09/1992', 'num_cupcakes_sold' => 30],
    ['date' => '05/10/1992', 'num_cupcakes_sold' => 25, 'revenue' => '$40'], 
    ['date' => '05/11/1992', 'revenue' => '$100'],
];
```

any good way of doing this?

Comment: 1. What pattern is behind this ? 2. Have you tried something?

Comment: I've tried a bunch of builtin php methods, `array_merge` and `array_merge_recursive` for example.

Comment: Can you make the values of the  `date` field into the keys for each array rather than using the numerical keys? That would make this significantly easier than two zero-indexed multidimensional arrays, and you could use a simple `array_merge()` to produce something like `cupcake_sales_revenue{ '05/10/1992' => { 'revenue' => '$40', 'num_cupcakes_sold' => 30 }`

Comment: The pattern? I have data about certain dates, but the data is incomplete at times. ie, some days I might only have `num_cupcakes_sold` other days I might only have `revenue`.  Some days I have both. I'd like to merge them together into an array so that I can key off `date` and see all the info that I have.

Comment: I am getting those arrays from mysql using my ORM's `as_array()` method. I could alter these arrays after I query for them, but eh

Comment: @johncorser Add ^ an attempt to your question! (BTW: I will assume that the $40 is a typo?!)

Comment: All of the data in this example was made up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and if the date is the same I merge the 2 arrays together with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and assign it to the results array. If they are different I just append both arrays to the result array in the current iteration.)

```
<?php

    $cupcake_sales_revenue = [];

    array_map(function($v1, $v2)use(&$cupcake_sales_revenue){
        if($v1["date"] == $v2["date"]) {
            $cupcake_sales_revenue[] = array_merge($v1, $v2);
        } else {
            $cupcake_sales_revenue[] = $v1;
            $cupcake_sales_revenue[] = $v2;
        }
    }, $cupcake_sales, $cupcake_revenue);

    print_r($cupcake_sales_revenue);


?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 05/09/1992
            [num_cupcakes_sold] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 05/10/1992
            [revenue] => $40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 05/11/1992
            [num_cupcakes_sold] => 25
            [revenue] => $100
        )

)
```

Comment: @johncorser You're welcome! (So you have a typo in your question you want to merge $100 not $40)